# How to echo >>someText in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, echo

I want to print to the console the exact text ">>someText"

I try

```
echo abb >>"cdd eee"
```

but that will print nothing and create file `cdd` with abb text inside it.

What syntax should I go with `echo` for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to "escape" special chars like `>` with a caret `^`:

```
echo abb ^>^>"cdd eee"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes

```
echo ">> cdd"
```

Comment: When using >> we often pass in the file path and that often include quotes so using quotes is not complete to my need. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use carat to escape the characters `echo ^>^>your text`

```
C:\echo ^>^>"cdd eee"
>>cdd
```